# Bibdesk incompatible webpage field

Tags: biblatex, biber, bibdesk

`! Package biblatex Error: No driver found.`
 throwing errors `I can't find a driver for the entry type 'url'` and `I can't find a driver for the entry type 'webpage'
and there is no fallback driver either.`  Why does BibDesk have me save in a format that BibLaTex doesn't use? CTAN seems to think webpages are type `online`.  Why isn't that an option in BibDesk?  http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf

Comment: The webpage entry type was added many years ago to support Norm Gray's [urlbst package](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-citeURL.html) in BibTeX styles. Since biblatex breaks compatibility with BibTeX in other areas, don't look for sympathy from the BibDesk developers (of which I was one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customise `BibDesk` to create an `online` entry type. Go to `Preferences` then `Fields`. You have the Advanced option to create "Custom Bibtex Types and Fields". There you can create an entry type `online` with the appropriate fields.

Alternatively, in your document, you can create an alias for `webpage`

```
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{webpage}{online}
```

Then `webpages` bibtex records will be considered as `online`.

Comment: It seems here that "your document" will be `bibliography.bib` rather than `main.tex`  I tried putting it in `main.tex` and XeLaTeX keeps pausing when it sees that line.

Comment: Isn't the syntax of `\DeclareBibliographyAlias` `\DeclareBibliographyAlias{<alias>}{<entrytype>}`, so shouldn't it be `\DeclareBibliographyAlias{webpage}{online}` and `\DeclareBibliographyAlias{url}{online}`, analogous to say `\DeclareBibliographyAlias{reference}{collection}` in `standard.bbx`?

Comment: @paynito The place to put this directive is *definitely* the `main.tex`, it will simply be ignored in the `.bib` file (with Biber it will cause a ... characters of junk warning).

Comment: @moewe correct the inversion of webpage and online

Answer (score 2):

There is no `webpage` nor `url` entry types for biblatex. The corresponding entry type is `online`, and `url` is a `mandatory field`for this entry type. It is an `optional field` for all entry types, as well as `urldate`.

Answer (score 1):

Also open your .bib in a text editor, find the @webpage entry. change to @online.  save.  reopen in BibDesk.  now online is one of your choices in the dropdown.  You can now create new online entries in this .bib only.  If you create a new .bib no more "online" choice.  I guess I should report this as a feature request at BibDesk.  Thanks @Bernard and @Guido for your answers.